# The Latex Font Catalogue - Calligra Font

Tags: fonts, input, font-encodings

I'm trying to get the following example working:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section*{Calligra}
\subsection*{\textbackslash calligra}
\normalfont\calligra
\input catalogue
\newpage
\normalfont\calligra
\input fonttable

\end{document}
```

This can be found under [Calligra - Text example](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligra/calligra.tex).

Now I have a problem with the `\input fonttable` line. Where can I download this file or how can I get this working?

Thx

Comment: if there's a situation where all you want is the font table, it can be obtained with `tex testfont` (that's plain tex, not latex).  it will ask for the name of the font to test; enter that, followed by "enter".  then `\table\bye' for one font, or `\table\vfil\eject\init` to enable another round.  you have to use the name of the font as it appears in the name of the `.tfm` file, or plain tex won't recognize it.

Comment: The `fonttable` package is able to make font tables.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a file from the [`hebtex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hebtex) package. I had to delete the last character from the file, since it has a DOS end-of-file marker in it.

> http://mirror.ctan.org/language/hebrew/hebtex/macros/tex_macros/fonttable.tex

Just to warn you, the file is **not**:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/nkarta/fonttable.tex